# Google Apps Script should only trigger during week days during hours 10 AM - 5 PM every hour

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```
function Buy() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName("Buy");  
  var Cvalues=sheet.getRange(2,3,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var Avalues=sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
  var results=[];

for(var i=0;i<Cvalues.length;i++){

if(Cvalues[i][0]<=-3){
      results.push(" "+ Avalues[i]);
      results.push("Price "+ Cvalues[i]);
      MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'Buy Alert',results.join("\n")); 
    }
  }

}
```

What code to include to make it trigger during **week days business hours 10 AM - 5 PM every hour**

Answer (score 0):

What about if you create an auxiliary function that triggers hourly, that evaluates the day and hour. If it's Mon-Fri and 10-17 it will trigger Buy(), if it isn't it won't happeng anything:

```
 function timingBuy() {
    var day = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-3","EEEE")
    var hour = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-3","hh")
    
    if(day.match("Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday") && hour >= 10 && hour< 17){Buy()}
    
}
```

[image]